# I need to get a certian part out of a string using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the `jsmith` part out of the following elements alt attribute

```
<img src="http://www.test.com" class="img-thumbnail" alt="John Smith (jsmith)">
```

So I'm running this

```
$('.img-thumbnail').attr('alt');
```

which gives me

```
"John Smith (jsmith)"
```

I need to get the 'jsmith' part out

any ideas?

Comment: Will the string you need to remove always be in (parenthesis) ?

Comment: Once you have the attribute value you just need standard Javascript string functions to extract the required piece. What have you tried? Regex match? Or `.indexOf()` plus `.slice()`? Or you could use `.split()`.

Comment: Yes, if the string is always be in (parenthesis) you can try Regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.img-thumbnail').attr('alt').match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]
```

Please note that this will only work if you want to get the text inside brackets.
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0veqkpmm/1/). Hope this helps

Comment: This gets want I need however it also gets the quotes. Thank you for you help. This guys @Aakash answer got exactly what I needed

Comment: Which way is better, the way your doing it or the way @Aakash is doing it.

Comment: @edward The both codes does the same thing..... But this code is little bit short....

Comment: Awesome, can you please tell me how the regex works?

Comment: It is explained perfectly in this question .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var matches = regExp.exec("John Smith (jsmith)");
console.log(matches[1]);
// Output jsmith
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this gave me exactly what I needed. can you please give me a short description of what its doing?

Comment: Sure, so we are using regular expression to get the value in the parenthesis. Here is the break down: `\(` - Match opening parenthesis, `(` - Begin to capture the string, `[^)]+` - Match one or more characters that are not `)` , `)`  - End capturing the string, `\)` - Match the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

try this also,

```
var temp = $('.img-thumbnail').attr('alt');
temp.substring(temp.indexOf('(')+1,temp.indexOf(')'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var value = $('img').attr('alt');
var newString = value.replace(new RegExp("\\(", "g") ,"~~~");
newString = newString.replace(new RegExp("\\)", "g") ,"~~~");
var finalString = newString.split('~~~');
alert(finalString[1])
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.